# How can I schedule my DAG to run every 5 minutes?

Tags: airflow, scheduled-tasks, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

I am using GCP cloud composer and have an airflow instance and a DAG.

The DAG's default arguments are these:

```
# Define the default arguments for the DAG.
default_args = {
    # If the start date is set to yesterday, Cloud Composer schedules the workflow to start immediately after the DAG
    # uploads.
    "start_date": datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 2) #yesterday
    ,"owner": "foobar"
    ,"schedule_interval": "*/5 * * * *"
    ,"tags": ["create_empty_dataset", "BigQuery"]
```

The DAG is running fine, but the schedule (every 5 minutes) is not. I tried using `datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)` but it didn't work. It just runs once and that's it. That's all I see:

[image: DAG]

Any ideas? I can edit and share the DAG code if necessary. It's simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with how you set the parameters.
`default_args` is set on DAG level but it contains parameters which are passed to operators. So when you set `schedule_interval` in `default_args` it means that this parameter is passed to all operators in your DAG and this has no meaning because the operators don't have `schedule_interval` parameter.

You should set `schedule_interval` in the DAG constractor:

```
DAG = (..., schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *", default_args=default_args)
```

Comment: I see. Yes I was doing this: `with DAG("foobar", default_args=default_args) as dag: ...`. Thank you. I will try what you said and come back to vote.

Comment: Yup, this did it for me: `with DAG("foobar", schedule_interval="*/5 * * * *", default_args=default_args) as dag:`